# Fluentd influxdb installation Error?

Tags: ruby, logging, influxdb, fluentd

I want to install influxdb plugin but I get thid error.

ERROR: Error installing fluent-plugin-influxdb:
   influxdb requires Ruby version >= 2.2.0.

I uninstalled my ruby and installed different versions from 2.0.0, 2.2.0, 2.3, 2.4
but the error still exist. would you please help me how to solve this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I installed latest version of ruby from here[ruby ftp](http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/)

Then I installed influxdb client
  `apt-get install influxdb-dev influxdb-client.`
After all downlad the latest version of fluend-plugin-influxdb from [git hub of plugin](https://github.com/fangli/fluent-plugin-influxdb/releases)
then I installed the plug in

```
/opt/td-agent/embedded/bin/gem install  fluent-plugin-influxdb
```

Answer (score -1):

td-agent ([Treasure Data's](http://www.treasuredata.com) packaged version of Fluentd) includes its own version of ruby within the /opt/td-agent/embedded/ directory and has links to ensure that it does not collide with other installations of ruby on the same box.

You can update to the latest version of td-agent, or if you need a specific version of Ruby then you should

1. Install Ruby version
2. Follow `gem install` instructions here: https://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/install-by-gem